# How to evaluate $\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{0}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{\sin x})}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{0}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{\sin x})}dx$$

I tried everything substitution,beta gamma function everything but I am unable to convert this into a standard form so How do I solve this problem.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2F(sinx%5E0.5)+from+x+%3D+0+to+x%3Dpi

Comment: I am not sure what happened here but it seems someone edited the question wrongly and changed the integration limits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\int^{\pi}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}} \mathrm dx = \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}} \mathrm dx + \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x}} \mathrm dx = 2 \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}} \mathrm dx$$

Then use the formula

$$B(x,y) = 2\int^{\pi/2}_0 (\sin t)^{2x-1} (\cos t)^{2y-1} dt$$

For $2y-1 = 0$ and $2x-1 = -\frac{1}{2}$ we have $x = \frac{1}{4}$ and $y = \frac{1}{2}$

$$2 \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}} \mathrm dx = \frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(1/4)}{\Gamma(3/4)} = \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

---

### Remark

It seems the question was edited

Define the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind as

$$F(\phi,k) = \int^{\phi}_0 \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 x}}$$

Suppose that $0 < \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $k=\sqrt{2}$

$$F(\phi,\sqrt{2}) = \int^{\phi}_0 \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{\cos(2x)}} = \frac{1}{2}\int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/2-2\phi} \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}  $$

$$F(\phi,\sqrt{2})= \frac{1}{2}\int^{\pi/2}_{0} \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}-\frac{1}{2}\int^{\pi/2-2\phi}_{0} \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}$$

Hence we have

$$\int^{\pi/2-2\phi}_{0} \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} =\frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}-2 F(\phi,\sqrt{2})$$

For the case $\phi = \pi/8$

$$\int^{\pi/4}_{0} \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} =\frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}-2 F(\pi/8,\sqrt{2})$$

Or using the other representation

$$\int^{\pi/4}_{0} \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} =\frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}-2 F\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \left. \right|2 \right)$$

Comment: And what is $\Gamma(1/4)$?

Comment: @Dr.MV, some transcendental number.

Comment: Yes, what is gained over writing $\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}\,dx$

Comment: @Dr.MV, this shows that the integral can't be simplified to a simpler representation at least in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Well, $\Gamma$ is not an elementary function. We can also write this in terms of the Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind.  Anyway (+1)

Comment: Well actually the upper limit should be pi/4 so your solution is a bit wrong...

Comment: @shramanshraman, the question was edited after I posted my answer. I added the solution for the newer version.

Comment: @Dr.MV, yeah. I added that one as well.

Comment: Well, I already gave a (+1).

Comment: Thank you sir Is there any way to calculate some approximate value of the integral...

Comment: @shramanshraman, you mean the numeric value here ?https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2F(sinx%5E0.5)+from+x+%3D+0+to+x%3Dpi%2F4

Comment: sir I was actually asking to solve this using trapezoidal or simpson one third or three eighth rule.
I just needed an approximate value near to 1.79 somehow for exam.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing both numerator and denominator by $\cos^2(x)$ and the substitution $\tan(x)=t$ may help.