# Equality of two elliptic integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

by [wolfram 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%7D%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B1-%5Csin%5E2%5Ctheta%5Csin%5E2%5Cphi%7D%7D%20d%5Cphi%20d%5Ctheta)   and [wolfram 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%7D%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B%5Csin%5Ctheta%5Csin%5Cphi%7D%7D%20d%5Cphi%20d%5Ctheta)

It's true that $\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi}} d\phi d\theta =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin\theta\sin\phi}} d\phi d\theta$ ?

If yes,  I need  a way to prove the equality of the following two integrals

I tried everything  but I am unable to convert  into a standard form so How do I solve this problem.

**Addition 1: For the second integral**
$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin\theta\sin\phi}} d\phi d\theta =\bigg(\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin\theta}}d\theta\bigg)^2 $ [and we can use that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202101/how-to-evaluate-int-frac-pi4-0-frac1-sqrt-sin-xdx?rq=1) $2 \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}} \mathrm dx = \frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(1/4)}{\Gamma(3/4)} = \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

**Addition 2: For the first integral**

Let $\displaystyle K(k)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 t}}dt$  ( Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind). [we know that](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Int%C3%A9grale_elliptique#Premi%C3%A8re_esp%C3%A8ce_2) $ \displaystyle K(k)=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\right)^2k^{2n}$. Then it's not difficult de show that $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi}} d\phi d\theta=(\pi /2 )^2 \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }(\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2})^3$.

The egality of the two integrals hold if we can calculte $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }(\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2})^3$$
[Wolfram gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%5Cpi%20%2F2%20%29%5E2%20%5Csum%20_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%20%7D%28%5Cfrac%7B%282n%29%21%7D%7B4%5En%28n%21%29%5E2%7D%29%5E3)

**Addition 3:**

[This link gives](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html)
[image]

Comment: Yes both integrals are $2K^2(1/2)$, where $K(m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Comment: @User: Any proof of it?

Comment: @User Thank you for confirmation . Proof would be welcome

Comment: @user According to Mathematica, the first integral is equal to $2K^2 (1/2)$ whilst the second one is equal to $\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi^2\Gamma(5/4)}{\Gamma(3/4)^3}$. The 2 values are not equal but the difference between them is numerically small ($-1.7 *10^{-15}$

Comment: @NN2 Both values are equal. You are speaking about numerical noice.

Comment: Almost a duplicate. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/809325/72031) and in particular [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3605552/72031).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The equivalence of the elliptic integrals can be shown in the following way:
$$\begin{align}
\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d\phi\, d\theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi}} 
& =\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}K(\sin\theta)d\theta\tag1\\
&=\int\limits_0^{1}\frac{K(r)dr}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\tag2\\
&=\int\limits_0^{1}\frac{K\left(\frac{2\sqrt k}{1+k}\right)dk}{\sqrt{k}(1+k)}\tag3\\
&=\int\limits_0^{1}\frac{K\left(k\right)dk}{\sqrt{k}}\tag4\\
&=\int\limits_0^{1}\frac{dk}{\sqrt{k}}
\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\phi}}\tag5\\
&=\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\phi\int\limits_0^{1}
 \frac{dk}{\sqrt{k}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\phi}}\tag6\\
&=\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\phi\int\limits_0^{\phi}
 \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\sin\theta\sin\phi}}\tag7\\
&=\frac12\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}
 \frac{d\phi\, d\theta}{\sqrt{\sin\theta\sin\phi}}.\tag8\\
\end{align}$$

Explanation:

$(1)$: Definition of the complete elliptic integral of the first kind
$K(k)=\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\phi}}$.

$(2)$: $\sin\theta\mapsto r$.

$(3)$: $r\mapsto\frac{2\sqrt k}{1+k}$.

$(4)$:  Landen's transformation $K(k)=\frac1{1+k}K\left(\frac{2\sqrt k}{1+k}\right)$.

$(5)$: Definition of the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

$(6)$: Interchange of integration order.

$(7)$: $k\mapsto\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\phi}$.

$(8)$: Use of the integrand symmetry.

Comment: thank you user, it's perfect

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Thank you for your recent my question and for your answer.

Answer (score 6):

I wish i have found out the following solution (thanks go to Etanche and Jandri).

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2 \varphi}}d\varphi d\theta\\
&\overset{z\left(\varphi\right)=\arcsin\left(\sin(\theta)\sin \varphi\right)}=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_0^ \theta\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(\theta-z)\sin(\theta+ z)}}dz\right)d\theta\tag1\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_{u}^{\pi-u}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u\sin v}}dv\right)du \tag2\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_{u}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u\sin v}}dv\right)du+\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi-u}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u\sin v}}dv\right)du}_{w=\pi-v}\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_{u}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u\sin v}}dv\right)du\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u\sin v}}dudv-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_{0}^{u}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u\sin v}}dv\right)du\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u\sin v}}dudv-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u}}\left(\int_0^{u}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin v}}dv\right)du\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u\sin v}}dudv-\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin v}}dv\right)^2\tag3\\
&=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u\sin v}}dudv}
\end{align}

$(1)$: $\displaystyle dz=\dfrac{\sqrt{\sin^2\theta-\sin^2 z}}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 z}}d\varphi$, $\sin^2 a-\sin^2 b=\sin(a-b)\sin(a+b)$

$(2)$: Perform the change of variable $u=\theta-z,v=\theta+z$

$(3)$: $\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(x)f^\prime(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(f^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-f^2(0)\right)$ and $\displaystyle f(x)=\int_0^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u}}du$

**(Edit: problem fixed again)**

Comment: Is not the integral in (2) pure imaginary?

Comment: @User: i'm working on it to fix this problem.

Comment: FDP nice solution

Comment: Could you explain the integration limits in (2)? They do not seem to be correct after your edit.

Comment: @User: the domain of integration is a triangle and its summits are $(0,0),(\frac{\pi}{2},0),(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ after the change of variable the domain of integration is still a triangle and its summits are $(0,0),(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}),(0,\pi)$.

Comment: I think you interchanged the definitions of $u $ and $v $. Please check.

Comment: @User: thanks. Fixed.